# Android Sqlite Database record deleted after updating the apk version

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

I have tried to implement the persistence layer of my application so that after updating the apk via Google Play, the database record can be maintained. When it comes ti the implementation, it erases all data after updating my apk version. Would you please tell me the way to back up and restore the sqlite records?

The below is my code

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hkgadddlden.sqlite";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

    private Dao<History, Integer> hDao = null;
    private Dao<Favourite, Integer> fDao = null;
    private Dao<Lm, Integer> lDao = null;
    private Dao<iconPlus, Integer> iDao = null;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database,ConnectionSource connectionSource)
    {
//      database.execSQL("create table history(t_id integer, topic text, page integer, PRIMARY KEY(t_id));");
//      database.execSQL("create table lm(t_id integer, PRIMARY KEY(t_id));");
//      database.execSQL("create table favourites(t_id integer, PRIMARY KEY(t_id));");

        try
        {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, History.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Favourite.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Lm.class); 
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, iconPlus.class);            
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        catch (java.sql.SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history"); //刪除舊有的資料表
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lm");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favourite");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iconPlus");        
        onCreate(db, connectionSource);

        try
        {
            List<String> allSql = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String sql : allSql)
            {
                db.execSQL(sql);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "exception during onUpgrade", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: if you dont change DATABASE_VERSION . the database dont remove.

Comment: I do not change the int inddeed , please check it carefuly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onUpgrade function is dropping all the tables.  That means you'll drop all the data.  If you want to not drop them, you have to write alter statements for each possible upgrade instead.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use a check if you are upgrading your database version

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 if (oldVersion<2) {
// do upgrade from 1 to 2
 }

 if (oldVersion<3) {
// do upgrade from 2 to 3, which will also cover 1->3,
// since you just upgraded 1->2
 }

// and so on
 }
```

as you are writing this code in your db

```
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history"); //刪除舊有的資料表
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lm");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favourite");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iconPlus");
```

it drops your table and data

Comment: and you can then use alter command if you had any changes in your tables.

Comment: Do you mean that since updating the apk is  upgrading  the database version, then given DATABASE_VERSION = 6 , if oldVersion <3  do back up and restore ?

Comment: how to change the db version?

Comment: your Db version DATABASE_VERSION = 6 is 6 that means..you have upgraded it..or intentionally you have used the 1st version as 6..any way..you need to change it to 7..to upgrade it.